# visual studio 2010 exporting unit test results

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I've created some data driven unit tests built using the Visual Studio 2010 testing framework and would like to make a permanent record of the results. I can export the usual .trx files, but would like to store the data in a database.

Aside from parsing the trx file to extract the info, is there an easy way to import the results into a repository such as Sql Server?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx), and its continuous integration features, it will save the overall result for you (and keep the file on the server disk/s unless you configure it otherwise). It does not keep single results in a queryable format, but what is the actual use case for that anyway?